# Android: can't get # symbol in phone call?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making `onclick` call to the given number with "#" symbol but can't get it. The call is working correctly. it's just can't get # with the number.

```
String myNumber = "783685353#";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + myNumber));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: What is the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
String myNumber = "783685353#";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +    Uri.encode(myNumber)     ));
startActivity(i);
```